# Spree - Bundle Error when pushing to heroku or elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a bit new to all this so this might be something obvious that I've overlooked but when I try to push my spree rails app to either heroku or beanstalk I get different errors involving bundle.

This one for Heroku:

```
Installing spree_core (2.0.0)
Gem::InstallError: spree_core requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing spree_core (2.0.0), and Bundler cannot

continue.
Make sure that `gem install spree_core -v '2.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

and this one for Elastic Beanstalk:

```
https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git (at 2-0-stable) is not checked out.
Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

My gemfile is here.
https://github.com/pjsim/spree_exporting_sardinia/blob/master/Gemfile

The app both bundles and runs fine on a local server and my ruby version is 1.9.3p392 so I don't understand why it fails here. Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ruby on Heroku is still 1.9.2. Try adding `ruby '1.9.3'` to your Gemfile to address that issue.

Comment: Sweet. That seems to have fixed it for heroku. I also needed to add :branch => "2-0-stable" on each spree gem in the gemfile. I'll work on getting beanstalk working later.